# What is complete induction, by example? $4(9^n) + 3(2^n)$ is divisible by 7 for all $n>0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

So, I've been revising for an exam and I came up against the question " prove $4(9^n) + 3(2^n)$ is divisible by 7 for all $n>0$.

Now, I know how to do this. If I assume $n=k$ divisible by $7$, then I need to show that $n=k+1$ is divisible by $7$. The easiest way to do this is to state that if we label $n_k=k$ and $n_{k+1} = k+1$ then if $7|n_{k+1}-n_{k}$ and $7|n_{k} \Rightarrow 7|n_{k+1}$.

So, without further ado, $4(9^k)9 - 4(9) + 3(2^k)2 - 3(2^k) = 8\cdot4(9^k) + 3\cdot2^k = 8(4(9^k) + 3(2^k)) - 7\cdot 3(2^k)$. As required. Now clearly for $n=0$ this expression is $7$ so divisible for all $n\geq 0$.

My question is, how would I go about proving this via [complete induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_induction#Complete_induction)? I asked because "proof by strong induction also accepted" was mentioned in the mark scheme. Now according to wikipedia, my first assumption is that not only is $n=k$ true but so is $n=k-1$ and so on down to $n=0$. How do I improve my expression of that and how do I go from there to show a proof using this technique?

**Edit**: The build up to the question is on the topic of induction, so that's why I proved it that way, but [Yuval Filmus](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1277/yuval-filmus) has pointed out that if we are simply asked to prove it, the fact that $9 \equiv 2 \mod(7)$ means the proof is trivial.

Comment: A proof by induction is also a proof by complete induction.

Comment: See my answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14984/what-is-the-second-principle-of-finite-induction/14987#14987

Comment: @Arturo Wow, thanks, might take me a while to digest that...

Comment: Be sure to ask questions if you have any. The answer does not address how to specifically apply it to this particular problem, though.

Comment: @Arturo I will probably have to; it looks a level more formal than I'm currently working so no doubt there'll be parts I don't understand.

Comment: Someone should note that the proof is immediate if we're allowed to use the basic fact that $9 \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way you can use complete induction is to notice that

$$9^{n+1} - 1 = 8(1 + 9 + 9^2 + \dots + 9^n)$$

and

$$2^{n+1} - 1 = 1 + 2 + 2^2 + \dots + 2^n$$

Mutiply the first by $\displaystyle 4$ and second by $\displaystyle 3$ and add them up. Now, notice that $\displaystyle 32(9^k) + 3(2^k) = 28(9^k) + 4(9^k) + 3(2^k)$

If you assume $\displaystyle 4(9^k) + 3(2^k)$ is divisible by $\displaystyle 7$ for $k=0, 1, 2, \dots, n$, then the above shows that it is also true for $\displaystyle n+1$.

Comment: Thanks, that is actually much less painful than I was expecting! :D

Answer (score 4):

A simple powerful way to prove by complete induction that $\rm\ f(n) = 4\cdot 9^n + 3\cdot 2^n \equiv 0\ \ (mod\ 7)\:$ is as follows: Put $\rm\ S\ f(n) = f(n+1)\:.\ $ Note $\rm\ S-9\ $ kills $\rm\ 9^n,\ $ and $\rm\ S-2\ $ kills $\rm\:2^n,\, $ [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/678917/242) $\rm (S-9)\ (S-2)\ $ kills $\rm\:f(n),\, $ i.e. $\rm\ f(n)\ $ satisfies  $\rm\ f(n+2) - 11\ f(n+1) + 18\ f(n) = 0.\, $ Now since $\rm\ 0\equiv f(0)\equiv f(1),\, $ using the recurrence and complete induction shows  $\rm\, f(n)\equiv 0\, $ for all $\rm\ n \in \mathbb N$.

An analogous complete induction proves that a solution of a monic linear recurrence is determined uniquely by its initial conditions - the **uniqueness theorem for linear difference equations**. Generally uniqueness theorems provide very powerful tools for proving equalities. See some of my [other posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:242+uniqueness+equalities) for further examples of such.

This is closely related to inductive proofs of the **recursion theorem**, which justifies the use of recursive definitions. For a nice introduction see Henkin: [On mathematical induction.](http://www.phys.uu.nl/%7Edockum/Leon%20Henkin%20-%20On%20mathematical%20induction.pdf)

Comment: I had to re-read that a few times, but wow, that's fantastic, +2 if I could.

Comment: What is $S$ in this case?