# Prove that $x_{n} = (n^{2}(n+1)^{2})/4$ via complete induction for the sequence $x_{n+1}=x_{n} + (n+1)^3$

Tags: recurrence-relations, induction

The sequence is described by $x_{n+1}=x_{n} + (n+1)^3$. Prove that $x_{n} = (n^{2}(n+1)^{2})/4$ via complete induction. I actually have two questions.

1. I'm a bit lost as to how to start the induction and what should be step, could someone please provide some assistance? I just want a line of thought, I would like to try to solve it, so please don't solve it for me. :)
2. I was able to prove it via "normal math", by reducing $x_{n+1}=x_{n} + (n+1)^3$ to $x_{n}=x_{n-1} + n^3$ and then replacing $x_{n-1}$ with the equation $x_{n-1} = ((n-1)^{2}  n^{2})/4$.

Then I did: $(n^{2}(n+1)^{2})/4 = ((n-1)^{2}  n^{2})/4 + n^3$

I then got $0=0$, which proves it's valid, right?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Why did your teacher ask you to prove this using strong induction? It's a perfect candidate for ordinary induction and I don't see a way to take advantage of the strong inductive hypothesis in a nontrivial way...

Comment: The start is a bit of a puzzle. You absolutely should also have been told what the "first" $x$ is. So you should have been told either that $x_0=0$ or that $x_1=1$. Without that "initial condition" kind of information, you *cannot* prove that the desired formula   holds.  Your procedure is basically correct. There is no need to change subscripts. If you don't, you need to show that $n^2(n+1)^2/4 +(n+1)^3=(n+1)^2(n+2)^2/4$, which is not really harder. I shudder a bit at the $0=0$ stuff. Just manipulate one expression or the other or both and show you get the same thing.

Comment: @user7530, I question myself the same. I still don't know how to proove it using strong induction though.

Comment: @André Nicolas, sorry, $x_0=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you don't need to 'start' a complete/strong induction. You simply prove that if the result is true for all $k\lt n$, then the result is true for $n$. If the argument works for every value of $n$, you are done (no basis of induction needed); [see my comments here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14984/what-is-the-second-principle-of-finite-induction/14987#14987). However, it is often the case that the argument does not work for *all* values of $n$ (especially small ones), and so "special cases" have to be proven explicitly.

So: we assume that for every $k\lt n$ we know that $x_k = (k^2(k+1)^2)/4$. We want to prove that $x_n = (n^2(n+1)^2)/4$.

Since $x_n = x_{n-1} + n^3$ (provided $n\gt 0$... see below), we have:
$$\begin{align*}
x_n &= x_{n-1} + n^3\\
&= \frac{(n-1)^2n^2}{4} + n^3 &\text{(induction hypothesis)}\\
&= n^2\left(\frac{(n-1)^2}{4} + n\right)\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}$$
and you should keep working to see if you can show that $x_n$ is indeed equal to $(n^2(n+1)^2)/4$.

However, the argument only works if $n\gt 0$; otherwise, there is no "$x_{n-1}$."

That means we would need to do the case $x_0$ directly. That is, we need to establish the **Special case** $n=1$.

<strike>**However**, you have no definition for $x_1$! That makes it pretty hard to prove.</strike>

<strike>So what we have here is that the formula is true for all $n$ *if* $x_1 = \frac{1^2(2)^2}{4} = 1$, because then the entire inductive argument will be valid. But if $x_1\neq 1$, then the formula does not hold for all $n$ (it fails already for $n=1$). Absent a definition of $x_1$, we don't know which one.</strike>

You note below that you know that $x_0=0$. So we just verify that the formula works for $n=0$ and we are done.

(In fact, this problem is "really" solved by ordinary mathematical induction rather than strong induction; not much of a problem).

---

As to your attempt: generally it is a bad idea to start with the equality you want to prove, manipulate it, and end up with something like "$0=0$". Because you can start with something *false* and end up with something true. For example, if you start with $1=-1$, you can then square both sides to get $1=1$; the latter is true, the former is not. So *before* you conclude that your original equality is true, you need to go through *every step* you took *in the reverse order* to verify that they are all "reversible". That is, you need to start with your $0=0$, and see if you can work *back up* to the equality you want.

That's why it is generally better to start with *one* side of the equation, and see if you can manipulate it until you get the *other* side in order to establish equality.

Comment: sorry! I completely forgot to add that $x_0=0$! But thanks for the great and fast answer!