# Show that every power of $2$ is sum of two squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to show, that every number of the form $2^n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) is a sum of two squares.
I don't have any idea how to start here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's false that every number $n$ is a sum of two squares: $3$ is not a sum of two squares (and in general, no number of the form $4n+3$ is a sum of two squares; and there are others, e.g., $21$ is not a sum of two squares). Fermat's Christmas Theorem characterizes the numbers that are sums of two squares.

Comment: Oh yes ofc, you are right, I changed it above

Comment: And along the way, obliterated the grammar and tag changes that had already been made to your post...

Comment: @Daniel: A negative, but I hope helpful, comment on "I don't know how to start here." Start with $n=1$, then do $n=2$, then do $n=3$, and so on. Soon everything will be clear.  Here goes: $2^1=2=1^2+1^2$; $2^2=4=2^2+0^2$; $2^3=8=2^2+2^2$; $2^4=4^2+0^2$; $2^5=4^2+4^2$; $2^6=8^2+0^2$.  The pattern is obvious, and now that we know what it is, writing down a formal proof is not hard. Note that the pattern is different for $n$ odd than for $n$ even.

Comment: @André: Yes you are right, I just didn't saw the pattern, nevertheless it's obvious :/

Comment: @Daniel: As to the general problem of representing a number as a sum of two squares, it takes a lot more experimentation to detect patterns, and a lot of effort to prove things. But here we have for all $n$ an essentially unique representation and a simple pattern. I was trying to say that a good first step for many problems is to examine "small" cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The statement that every natural number $n$ is a sum of two squares is false. For example, $3$ is not a sum of any two squares.

**Hint:** Note that $2^n=2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}$ and $2^n=2^n+0$. Which statement should you use for which $n$?

Comment: $2^n=2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}$ for odd n's and the other statement for even n's?

Comment: @Daniel: Exactly :)

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks for the hint :-)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

1. Show that if $a$ and $b$ are each a sum of two squares, then so is $ab$.
2. Then show that $2$ is a sum of two squares.
3. Then use induction.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT** $\rm\quad 2\ (a^2 + b^2)\ =\ (a + b)^2 + (a - b)^2\ $ yields the inductive step.

**REMARK** $\ $ Writing $\ 2\ = 1^2 + 1^2\ $ shows that the above is nothing but a special case of the well-known [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) for composing sums of squares. This special *doubling* case was known much earlier than the general case. It plays a key role in my [speculative reconstruction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27317/242) of  $\rm\ FLT_4\equiv $ **Fibonacci's Lost Theorem,**  the area of an integral 
pythagorean triangle $\rm\ne n^2\:.$

Comment: More generally see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/90628/242)