# Prove that $2^{n} s$ can be written as the sum of perfect squares, where $s$ is the sum of perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need require assistance in proving that $$2^{n} s$$ can be written as the sum of two perfect squares, where $$s$$ is a sum of two perfect squares. My teacher has told me I'm not allowed to use induction and I'm not really sure how to go about it.

If anyone could nudge me in the night direction, I'd be appreciative.

Comment: Hint: Think about the case when n is even and the case when n is odd

Comment: Relevant question (possible duplicate): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/100506/264

Comment: I've thought about that...but I get that it can be expressed as the sum of 2 perfect squares when 'n' is odd and it can't when 'n' is even but I'm required to show it works for all natural n :(

Comment: As a nuclear overkill, you can use [Fermat's classification of numbers which can be written as the sum of 2 squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares). But please just follow Amr's hint.

Comment: Hint: zero is a perfect square.

Comment: Because you say you have trouble when $n$ is even, I thought it might help to remind you that $0$ is a perfect square.  E.g., $2^2=2^2+0^2$.

Comment: Ahh, silly me. Thanks very much!

Comment: @user78416 Note that for the revised problem, the $n$ even case is the 'easy' one - if $s=x^2+y^2$, then $2^{2k}s = (2^kx)^2+(2^ky)^2$; the $n$ odd case is handled by Calvin's answer.

Comment: How would induction even be used? This is not a problem of proving that a property holds over a set, but of finding an instance. "Your homework consists of driving nails; note that the use of a saw is not allowed".

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If the numbers $x$ and $y$ can each be written as the sum of 2 perfect squares, then so can the number $xy$. This is known as the [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_identity).

You can either prove this statement yourself, or click on the Wikipedia link.

Comment: So that covers the case of even n! Thanks very much! :D

Answer (score 1):

In the case that $ n $ is odd, let $ s = k^2 $ and $ n = 2m + 1$. Hence $$ 2^{2m + 1}k^2 = \left(2^m k\right)^2 + \left(2^mk\right)^2 $$ Otherwise, $ n = 2m $ and we have that $$ 2^{2m}k^2 = \left(2^m k \right)^2 + 0^2 $$
No induction needed here. $ m $ and $ k $ are both in $ \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} $.

You might think the zero is "cheating" but it is definitely necessary in some cases such as $ 2^n s = 16 $.

Comment: There is a problem when n is odd

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a typo in the original problem :( s is not a perfect square, it is the sum of two perfect squares, sorry :(