# Help with Elementary number theory please

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, geometric-progressions

Use the second principle of finite induction to establish that for all $n\geq1$ :
$$a^n-1=(a-1)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+a^{n-3}+\cdots+a+1\right) $$
Step by step explanation please! I'm confused how the second principle of finite induction is different from the first.

Comment: For those who may wonder, it [appears that](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/14984/242) the "second principle of finite induction" is an uncommon name for what is usually called [complete induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction), or strong induction, or course of values induction.

Answer (score 4):

You can use that
\begin{align}
a^{k+1}-1&=a(a^k-1)+(a-1)\\
&=a(a-1)(a^k+\cdots+a+1)+(a-1)\\
&=(a-1)(a^{k+1}+\cdots+a^2+a)+(a-1)\\
&=(a-1)(a^{k+1}+\cdots+a+1)
\end{align}
assuming you know that the theorem holds for $n=k$, but this is just simple induction (I think), not the so called 'second principle' of finite induction.

To answer your question:
The second principle uses all cases $n=1$ up to $n=k$ as induction hypothesis, instead of only $n=k$. See [this answer on a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14984/91741) for more information.

**EDIT**
A quick google search returned the page above, which uses the similar wording. I had never heard of it (the phrasing 'second principle' instead of 'strong induction') myself too.

Comment: What is the "second principle" of induction ? I have never heard of that.

Comment: neither have I.. but that is how my textbook question was worded. I was wondering what it meant.

Comment: Is it the modified induction step : If the claim holds for all k<n, then it holds for n ?

Comment: @Peter, Yes, that is the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Second principle of finite induction establishes if the given statement is true for $n$ from $1,2,3... n$. Then it is true for $n+1$.

$$a^1 -1= a-1 \\
a^2 -1= (a-1)(a+1)$$
say $n \ge 3$
assume
$$a^{n} -1 =(a-1)(a^{n-1} +a^{n-2} +a^{n-3}.....+a+1)$$
we have to prove this for $n+1$.
$a^{n+1} -1$ can be written as $(a+1)(a^{n-1})-a(a^{n-1} -1)$
we already know $a^n -1$ is $(a-1)(a^{n-1} +a^{n-2} +a^{n-3}.....+a+1)$

Let $S=a^{n-1} +a^{n-2} +a^{n-3}.....+a+1$
so I can write $a^{n+1} -1$ as $(a+1)(a-1)S -a(S-a^{n-1})(a-1)$
which on simplifying gives
the required statement to prove

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math thank you.

Comment: sorry I am new here. so will do from next time

Comment: Thank you for commenting

Comment: You're welcome. You have a tutorial and reference here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: yeah Thanks. will learn to use MathJax